# order of multiple loop in the same line

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
(2:red, 10:white) > (3:blue, 7:green)
.................
................
```

I have a file of this type. I need to get for every color its value beside it. I tried this

```
for line in file.splitlines():
a, b = line.split(">")
a_value = [one[0] for one in sec for sec in item.split(':') in sec for sec in a.split(',')]
```

But I have a problem in the multiple for looping, can someone help?

Comment: Is the file gigantic or is it ok to have all of it in memory?

Comment: yes, they can repeat wihin the file

Comment: @gho, then the easiest and most efficient  thing to do is to store the values in a container to handle repeated keys

Answer (score 2):

### Repeating colors

File content:

```
file = """(2:red, 10:white) > (3:blue, 7:green)
(12:red, 110:white) > (13:blue, 17"""
```

`defaultdict` with `list` works well here:

```
from collections import defaultdict

colors = defaultdict(list)

for line in file.splitlines():
    for col in line.split('>'):
        for entry in col.strip()[1:-1].split(','):
            num, name = entry.split(':')
            colors[name].append(int(num))
```

Result is a list of values for each color:

```
>>> colors
defaultdict(list,
            {'blue': [3, 13],
             'green': [7, 17],
             'red': [2, 12],
             'white': [10, 110]})
```

### Non-repeating colors

Assuming that all colors are unique, you can do something like this:

```
colors = {}
for line in file.splitlines():
    for col in line.split('>'):
        for entry in col.strip()[1:-1].split(','):
            num, name = entry.split(':')
            colors[name] = int(num)

>>> colors
{'blue': 3, 'green': 7, 'red': 2, 'white': 10}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have repeated keys you cannot use a dict comprehension, you can use a `defaultdict` storing all the colour values in lists with the colours as keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in map(str.rstrip,f):
        for s in line.split(" > "):
            for sub in s[1:-1].split(", ", 1):
                v, k = sub.split(":", 1)
                d[k].append(v)
```

input:

```
(2:red, 10:white) > (3:blue, 7:green)
(12:red, 19:white) > (22:blue, 22:green)
(34:red, 14:white) > (19:blue, 13:green)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'blue': ['3', '22', '19'], 'white': ['10', '19', '14'], 'green': ['7', '22', '13'], 'red': ['2', '12', '34']})
```

if you want to output as tuples you just need to iterate over the items:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    for val in v:
        print((k, val))
```

Output:

```
('blue', '3')
('blue', '22')
('blue', '19')
('white', '10')
('white', '19')
('white', '14')
('green', '7')
('green', '22')
('green', '13')
('red', '2')
('red', '12')
('red', '34')
```

If you want to use a regex:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

d = defaultdict(list)

with open("in.txt") as f:
    r = re.compile("\d+:\w+")
    for line in map(str.rstrip, f):
        for s in r.findall(line):
            v, k = s.split(":", 1)
            d[k].append(v)
```

Output will be the same:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'blue': ['3', '22', '19'], 'white': ['10', '19', '14'], 'green': ['7', '22', '13'], 'red': ['2', '12', '34']}
```